# word counting program not producing desired output in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm writing the code for word count in spark but it giving me the output as an array and some time the rdd after using the map:-

```
Array[(String, Int)] = Array((Welcome,1), (Programmings,1), (Spark,1), (in,1), (Saaransh,1))
```

I've already tried the code ->

```
val f = sc.textFile("/root/Desktop/BigData/ScalaProgram/WordCount.txt")
val fm = f.flatMap(x => x.split(" ")).map(y => (y,1)).reduceByKey((a, b) => a+b).collect

val i = f.flatMap(x => x.split(" "))
val j = i.map(y => (y,1)).reduceByKey((a, b)=> a+b)
```

I want the output as a **single integer** which represents the total number of words in a single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the wording a little confusing, but if this is the question:

> I want the output as a singles integer which is a number of words in a
>   file.

then this is all you need:

```
val fileRDD = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/some.txt")
val count_words_in_single_file = fileRDD.flatMap(x => x.split(" ")).map(y => (y,1)).map(w => (w._2)).sum
```

This does it per a single file as input, if you have multiple files per input, then the solution differs again requiring sc.wholeTextFiles with name of file gotten, unless you want to count all words over all files.

You may want to consider datasets in future.